# Alternatives to standard functions of C++ to get speed optimization

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

Just to clarify that I also think the title is a bit silly. We all know that most built-in functions of the language are really well written and fast (there are ones even written by assembly). Though may be there still are some advices for my situation. I have a small project which demonstrates the work of a search engine. In the indexing phase, I have a filter method to filter out unnecessary things from the keywords. It's here:

```
bool Indexer::filter(string &keyword)
{
    // Remove all characters defined in isGarbage method
    keyword.resize(std::remove_if(keyword.begin(), keyword.end(), isGarbage) - keyword.begin());

    // Transform all characters to lower case
    std::transform(keyword.begin(), keyword.end(), keyword.begin(), ::tolower);

    // After filtering, if the keyword is empty or it is contained in stop words list, mark as invalid keyword
    if (keyword.size() == 0 || stopwords_.find(keyword) != stopwords_.end())
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

At first sign, these functions (alls are member functions of STL container or standard function) are supposed to be fast and not take many time in the indexing phase. But after profiling with Valgrind, the inclusive cost of this `filter` is ridiculous high: 33.4%. There are three standard functions of this filter take most of the time for that percentage: `std::remove_if` takes 6.53%, `std::set::find` takes 15.07% and `std::transform` takes 7.71%.

So if there are any thing I can do (or change) to reduce the instruction times cost by this filter (like using parallellizing or something like that), please give me your advice. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Thanks for all your suggestion. So in brief, I've summarize what I need to do is:
1) Merge `tolower` and `remove_if` into one by construct my own loop.
2) Use `unordered_set` instead of `set` for faster `find` method.
Thus I've chosen `Mark_B`'s as the right answer.

Comment: I dunno, but have you considered the possibility that filtering actually *is* an expensive operation?

Comment: +1 for profiling instead of guessing.

Comment: Try it with `stopwords_` as a `std::unordered_set` rather than a `std::set`. If that goes well, then consider changing that `unordered_set` to use a case-insensitive hash function, rather than separately lower-casing and then finding.

Comment: Does stopwords_ remain relatively static once it is created?  If so, then you can use a sorted vector instead.

Comment: Perhaps in your case this applies: [Why you shouldn't use set (and what you should use instead)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=why%20not%20to%20use%20set%20and%20what%20to%20use%20instead&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flafstern.org%2Fmatt%2Fcol1.pdf&ei=AwCgT9DICcHjiAKpuaCyAQ&usg=AFQjCNEOAgURQSrd8Z8uBzP3m6l6Yd3qwA). For another example take a listen to Bjarne Stroustrup's comments on compact data structures from his [Going Native talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style) (see slide 45).

Comment: Can you merge the `transform` and the `remove_if` into one?

Comment: Another thought: test whether `keyword.size()` is greater than the longest string in `stopwords_` before doing the relatively expensive `find` operation. This is assuming of course that you can figure out which is the longest stopword once, before you do a lot of filtering. It may well be that all your stopwords are pretty short.

Comment: Can you add a minimal, but complete test case to this so it's possible to easily answer objectively rather than purely based on speculations?

Comment: @awoodland: I don't know any `transform_if` so not purely with the STL I think.

Comment: @MatthieuM. boost filter iterators seem to be as close as you can get to `transform_if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, are you certain that optimization and inlining are enabled when you compile?

Assuming that's the case, I would first try writing my own transformer that combines removing garbage and lower-casing into one step to prevent iterating over the keyword that second time.

There's not a lot you can do about the find without using a different container such as `unordered_set` as suggested in a comment.

Is it possible for your application that doing the filtering really just is a really CPU-intensive part of the operation?

Comment: First question: No, because when profiling, I need to leave my program in debug mode. Certainly, when using it, the -O3 flag should be enabled.

Comment: Last question: I want to minimize the work of filtering as much as possible to reduce the time of indexing. This is the last part I could optimize in my program.

Comment: @herophuong: Profiling is meant to measure efficiency. Templates are only efficient when inlined (implying `-O2`). Therefore profiling without `-O2` is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a boost filter iterator you can merge the `remove_if` and `transform` into one, something like (untested):

```
keyword.erase(std::transform(boost::make_filter_iterator(!boost::bind(isGarbage), keyword.begin(), keyword.end()),
                             boost::make_filter_iterator(!boost::bind(isGarbage), keyword.end(), keyword.end()),
                             keyword.begin(),
                            ::tolower), keyword.end());
```

This is assuming you want the side effect of modifying the string to still be visible externally, otherwise pass by `const` reference instead and just use `count_if` and a predicate to do all in one. You can build a hierarchical data structure (basically a tree) for the list of stop words that makes "in-place" matching possible, for example if your stop words are `SELECT, SELECTION, SELECTED` you might build a tree:

```
|- (other/empty accept)
\- S-E-L-E-C-T- (empty, fail)
             |- (other, accept)
             |- I-O-N (fail)
             \- E-D (fail)
```

You can traverse a tree structure like that simultaneously whilst transforming and filtering without any modifications to the string itself. In reality you'd want to compact the multi-character runs into a single node in the tree (probably).

You can build such a data structure fairly trivially with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class keywords {
  struct node {
        node() : end(false) {}
    std::map<char, std::unique_ptr<node>> children;
        bool end;
  } root;

  void add(const std::string::const_iterator& stop, const std::string::const_iterator c, node& n) {
    if (!n.children[*c])
      n.children[*c] = std::unique_ptr<node>(new node);

    if (stop == c+1) {
      n.children[*c]->end = true;
      return;
    }
    add(stop, c+1, *n.children[*c]);
  }
public:
  void add(const std::string& str) {
    add(str.end(), str.begin(), root);
  }

  bool match(const std::string& str) const {
    const node *current = &root;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while(current && pos < str.size()) {
      const std::map<char,std::unique_ptr<node>>::const_iterator it = current->children.find(str[pos++]);
      current = it != current->children.end() ? it->second.get() : nullptr;
    }
    if (!current) {
      return false;
    }
    return current->end;
  }
};

int main() {
  keywords list;
  list.add("SELECT");
  list.add("SELECTION");
  list.add("SELECTED");
  std::cout << list.match("TEST") << std::endl;
  std::cout << list.match("SELECT") << std::endl;
  std::cout << list.match("SELECTOR") << std::endl;
  std::cout << list.match("SELECTED") << std::endl;
  std::cout << list.match("SELECTION") << std::endl;
}
```

This worked as you'd hope and gave:

```
0
1
0
1
1
```

Which then just needs to have `match()` modified to call the transformation and filtering functions appropriately e.g.:

```
const char c = str[pos++];
if (filter(c)) {
  const std::map<char,std::unique_ptr<node>>::const_iterator it = current->children.find(transform(c));
}
```

You can optimise this a bit (compact long single string runs) and make it more generic, but it shows how doing everything in-place in one pass might be achieved and that's the most likely candidate for speeding up the function you showed.

(Benchmark changes of course)

Comment: This is good, but won't you end up with an empty string?  You've transformed keyword in place to only include garbage characters and then told it to erase them.  I think you meant to use "resize()" like the OP, but I tend to think this is probably unwarranted (unless it really is).  You could also simply transform in place by inverting your filter operator.

Comment: @CrazyEddie - I meant to invert the filter operation, I'll add a std::not1 to fix it

Comment: change of plan - I used the ! operator on boost::bind for convenience

Comment: The tree in question is called a `Trie` :)

Comment: Note that `::tolower` might be a bottleneck in this implementation.

Comment: @MarkRansom - it gets called no more than a version that has multiple separated passes in either of my suggestions

Comment: @awoodland, it's possible to move `tolower` out of the time-critical loop. See my answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom - true, you could implement something like that with the trie building phase on this solution though still. (There's also nothing that suggests that `isGarbage()` isn't looking at some global state and giving different results between different calls for the same input though)

Comment: That's a good point, `isGarbage` quite plausibly could be locale-dependent. It goes without saying that anything whose results you cache, needs to be a pure function (or you need to know when to invalidate your cache). Although possibly it shouldn't go without saying :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might make this faster by making a single pass through the string, ignoring the garbage characters.  Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
std::string normalizedKeyword;
normalizedKeyword.reserve(keyword.size())
for (auto p = keyword.begin(); p != keyword.end(); ++p)
{
    char ch = *p;
    if (!isGarbage(ch))
        normalizedKeyword.append(tolower(ch));
}

// then search for normalizedKeyword in stopwords
```

This should eliminate the overhead of `std::remove_if`, although there is a memory allocation and some new overhead of copying characters to `normalizedKeyword`.

Comment: Note that because you have introduced a temporary you have a memory allocation instead of in-place modification. Still the idea is good.

Comment: Your suggestion has some typo but I still get the idea. Though I think modifying the keyword in-place with that iterator is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If a call to isGarbage() does not require synchronization, then parallelization should be the first optimization to consider (given of course that filtering one keyword is a big enough task, otherwise parallelization should be done one level higher). Here's how it could be done - in one pass through the original data, multi-threaded using Threading Building Blocks:

```
    bool isGarbage(char c) {
    return c == 'a';
}

struct RemoveGarbageAndLowerCase {
    std::string result;
    const std::string& keyword;

    RemoveGarbageAndLowerCase(const std::string& keyword_) : keyword(keyword_) {}

    RemoveGarbageAndLowerCase(RemoveGarbageAndLowerCase& r, tbb::split) : keyword(r.keyword) {}

    void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<size_t> &r) {
        for(size_t i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) {
            if(!isGarbage(keyword[i])) {
                result.push_back(tolower(keyword[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    void join(RemoveGarbageAndLowerCase &rhs) {
        result.insert(result.end(), rhs.result.begin(), rhs.result.end());
    }
};

void filter_garbage(std::string &keyword) {
    RemoveGarbageAndLowerCase res(keyword);
    tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, keyword.size()), res);
    keyword = res.result;
}

int main() {
    std::string keyword = "ThIas_iS:saome-aTYpe_Ofa=MoDElaKEYwoRDastrang";

    filter_garbage(keyword);

    std::cout << keyword << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the final code could be improved further by avoiding data copying, but the goal of the sample is to demonstrate that it's an easily threadable problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't the standard functions, it's your use of them.  You are making multiple passes over your string when you obviously need to be doing only one.

What you need to do probably can't be done with the algorithms straight up, you'll need help from boost or rolling your own.

You should also carefully consider whether resizing the string is actually necessary.  Yeah, you might save some space but it's going to cost you in speed.  Removing this alone might account for quite a bit of your operation's expense.

Comment: The `resize` should only change the `_M_size` member so is basically free, however I would still consider using the `erase` function that takes a pair of iterators because it's more idiomatic: `erase-remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to combine the garbage removal and lower-casing into a single step. It won't work for multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8, but neither did your original code. I assume `0` and `1` are both garbage values.

```
bool Indexer::filter(string &keyword)
{
    static char replacements[256] = {1}; // initialize with an invalid char
    if (replacements[0] == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0;  i < 256;  ++i)
            replacements[i] = isGarbage(i) ? 0 : ::tolower(i);
    }
    string::iterator tail = keyword.begin();
    for (string::iterator it = keyword.begin();  it != keyword.end();  ++it)
    {
        unsigned int index = (unsigned int) *it & 0xff;
        if (replacements[index])
            *tail++ = replacements[index];
    }
    keyword.resize(tail - keyword.begin());

    // After filtering, if the keyword is empty or it is contained in stop words list, mark as invalid keyword
    if (keyword.size() == 0 || stopwords_.find(keyword) != stopwords_.end())
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

The largest part of your timing is the `std::set::find` so I'd also try `std::unordered_set` to see if it improves things.

Comment: I would propose to cache `keyword.end()`, just in case it's not done automatically. And move the array to static memory instead of having a function to compute it. This is something that can be directly mapped during static initialization if it's filled up directly (and could thus be `const`).

Comment: @MatthieuM., perhaps you didn't notice that the `replacements` array *is* static and will be computed only once?

Comment: Very pedantic niggle - make sure `isGarbage` offers the nothrow guarantee. Otherwise you could get different (and probably unwanted) behavior between the case where it only throws when it sees a character it doesn't like, and the case where it throws the first time the filter is called regardless of the string value, and leaves the static `replacements` array in a broken state.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I did, but we could avoid computation entirely, which would simplify the code of the function.

Comment: What's the purpose of the first IF statement? If you initialise the char array in the previous line surely the IF statement condition will always be satisfied?

Comment: @user1107474, the array is static so it keeps the same value each time the function is called. The condition will be true the first time and false thereafter, as long as 0 and 1 are both garbage values.

Answer (score -1):

I would implement it with lower level C functions, something like this maybe (not checking this compiles), doing the replacement in place and not resizing the keyword.

1. Instead of using a set for garbage characters, I'd add a static table of all 256 characters (yeah, it will work for ascii only), with 0 for all characters that are ok, and 1 for those who should be filtered out. something like:

`static const char GARBAGE[256] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...., 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ... }`;

then for each character in offset `pos` in `const char *str` you can just check `if (GARBAGE[str[pos]] == 1)`;

this is more or less what an unordered set does, but will have much less instructions. `stopwords` should be an unordered set if they're not.

now the filtering function (I'm assuming ascii/utf8 and null terminated strings here):

```
bool Indexer::filter(char *keyword)
{

    char *head = pos;
    char *tail = pos;

    while (*head != '\0') {
        //copy non garbage chars from head to tail, lowercasing them while at it
        if (!GARBAGE[*head])  {
           *tail = tolower(*head);
           ++tail; //we only advance tail if no garbag
        }
        //head always advances
        ++head;
    }
    *tail = '\0';

    // After filtering, if the keyword is empty or it is contained in stop words list, mark as invalid keyword
    if (tail == keyword || stopwords_.find(keyword) != stopwords_.end())
        return false;


    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sold on the idea of making it look more like C offering any benefits

Comment: @awoodland you can do the same with std::string::iterator. the key thing here is to do it in place.

Comment: awoodland - you're right, there's no reason for it.  You could implement exactly the same algorithm with iterators if you really wanted to.  You don't need to change to C strings--that's kind of crazy advice.